# How to get the filepath when using DotLiquid Include Method?

Tags: dotliquid

I was create Include method, like below code.

the products.liquid like below

```liquid
{% include product-list-item %}
```

The include method like below:

```cs
public class IncludeFileSystem : IFileSystem
{
    public string ReadTemplateFile(Context context, string templateName)
    {
        string themesLocalPath = "";
        var templatePath = LiquidTemplateHelper.ResolveTemplatePath(templateName, themesLocalPath);
        return LiquidTemplateHelper.ReadTemplateByPath(templatePath);
    }
}
```

but for different users, they load different "product-list-item" from the file.
How to set the get and set the "themesLocalPath" values?

Comment: it was fixed. There are two ways to use a file system:

1. If you want to set it globally, set Template.FileSystem.
2. If you want to set it per-render, set renderParameters.Registers[“file_system”] in your Template.Render call. That allows you, for example, to create a difference instance of your custom file system per user.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to use a file system:

1. If you want to set it globally, set `Template.FileSystem`
2. If you want to set it per-render, set `renderParameters.Registers["file_system"]` in your `Template.Render` call. That allows you, for example, to create a difference instance of your custom file system per user.